# AssertionError while updating conda

Tags: conda

I've tried to update conda using the following command :

```
~$ conda update conda
```

It outputs the following message:

```
WARNING conda.base.context:use_only_tar_bz2(632): Conda is constrained to only 
using the old .tar.bz2 file format because you have conda-build installed, 
and it is <3.18.3.  Update or remove conda-build to get smaller downloads 
and faster extractions.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - 

The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully

The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

- defaults/linux-64::cytoolz==0.9.0.1=py37h14c3975_1

- and around 100 more

Preparing transaction: done

Verifying transaction: done

Executing transaction: done

ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(637): An error occurred while installing 
package 'None'.

AssertionError()

Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

AssertionError()
```

I have also tried

```
~$ conda update --all
```

but it gave me the same error as before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding this matter i have found a solution that is not well explained but solve the problem:

first : using the command :

```
~$ conda install anaconda
```

this resolve the problem of the environment inconsistency .

second : using the command:

```
 ~$ conda update conda
```

the command will be executed with no problems and conda will be updated proberly.

Comment: not sure why  there is ~% before the command, but worked also in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and I use miniconda, so I don't want to install anaconda. It worked for me to update python from 3.6 to 3.7 as follows:

```
$ conda install python=3.7
```

When I did this, conda updated automatically to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The commands made me fail to conda install packages,lead to "'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from conda's operating environment."

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.9.0
pip install setuptools==38.6.0
```

then I try those ...

```
conda update -f conda
conda install -f codna
```

The second line help me solve the problem. 
I'm forwardly looking for the why.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Ubuntu), Muhammed solution didn't work for me.
[This answer](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8832#issuecomment-506915956) worked!

```
$ conda install anaconda
$ conda update conda-build
```